# Nest can't resolve dependencies of a service

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

**Error**: `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the StatusService (?). Please make sure that the argument "StatusEntityRepository" at index [0] is available in the StatusModule context.`

**StatusModule**:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { StatusPersistenceModule } from './persistence/status-persistence.module';
import { StatusService } from './status.service';

@Module({
  imports: [StatusPersistenceModule],
  providers: [StatusService],
  exports: [StatusService],
})
export class StatusModule {}
```

**StatusPersistenceModule**:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { StatusRepository } from './status-repository.interface';
import { StatusEntity } from './status.entity';
import { StatusRepositoryImpl } from './status.repository';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([StatusEntity])],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: StatusRepository,
      useClass: StatusRepositoryImpl,
    },
  ],
  exports: [StatusRepository],
})
export class StatusPersistenceModule {}
```

**StatusService**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Nullable } from 'src/common/types/nullable.type';
import { EntityCondition } from 'src/common/types/entity-condition.type';
import { StatusEntity } from './persistence/status.entity';
import { StatusRepository } from './persistence/status-repository.interface';

@Injectable()
export class StatusService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(StatusEntity)
    private readonly statusRepository: StatusRepository,
  ) {}

  async findOne(
    fields: EntityCondition<StatusEntity>,
  ): Promise<Nullable<StatusEntity>> {
    return this.statusRepository.findOne(fields);
  }
}
```

This `StatusModule` is used in `UserModule`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { RoleModule } from '../role/role.module';
import { StatusModule } from '../status/status.module';
import { UserPersistenceModule } from './persistence/user-persistence.module';

@Module({
  imports: [RoleModule, StatusModule, UserPersistenceModule],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**AppModule**:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthModule } from './modules/auth/auth.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { TypeOrmConfigService } from './database/typeorm-config.service';
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import appConfig from './config/app.config';
import databaseConfig from './database/config/database.config';
import authConfig from './modules/auth/config/auth.config';
import { UserModule } from './modules/user/user.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [appConfig, databaseConfig, authConfig],
      envFilePath: ['.env'],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: TypeOrmConfigService,
      dataSourceFactory: async (options: DataSourceOptions) => {
        return new DataSource(options).initialize();
      },
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Putting `StatusModule` in the `AppModule` `imports` does nothing.

Does anyone know why Nest can't resolve the `StatusRepository` injection in the `StatusService`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're using a wrong token provider for that `private readonly statusRepository: StatusRepository`

The `@InjectRepository(StatusEntity)` implies in an injecting the provider registered by `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([StatusEntity])` (under the token `"StatusEntityRepository"`), not the `StatusRepository` class you've registered yourself at `StatusPersistenceModule`. It is the same as doing:

```
@Inject("StatusEntityRepository")
private readonly statusRepository: StatusRepository,
```

which is clearly wrong as the `StatusPersistenceModule` didn't export that provider.

I didn't follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I follow what you're saying. I fixed the mistake and renamed my StatusEntity to Status. The entire code stayed the same, but now I'm getting `Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the StatusService (?). Please make sure that the argument "StatusRepository" at index [0] is available in the StatusModule context.` - it's like Nest can't figure out that `StatusPersistenceModule` module exports `StatusRepository` provider and that module is imported in `StatusModule`, as per the code provided in the question...

Comment: as long as you've a provider registered with the token `"StatusRepository"` (notice that it's an string) and exported at `StatusPersistenceModule` module, it will work just fine. Which is not the case. By 'token' I mean the value of the `provide` prop.

Comment: Yes, the problem was I was using some boilerplate code and ended up creating my own repository class, and also using @InjectRepository decorator, which is clearly wrong